# Form to JS Object: change default serializeArray() data structure to make Geospatial-compatible object

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I am using the following to convert a form to JS object and then insert it in a MongoDB collection...

```
form={};

$.each($('#myform').serializeArray(), function() {
    form[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

this produces something in the lines of:

```
{ "name" : "value", "name" : "value", "name" : "value", "name" : "value" }
```

I would like to get something like:

```
{
        "aaa": "111",
        "bbb": "222",
        "ccc": "333",
        "loc": {
            "longitude": "-11.34354656",
            "latitude": "-45.4566546"
        }
}
```

How should I modify the jQuery to get that?
I saw that there are plugins for the job but I'm wondering if the solution is simpler than that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve want I wanted I used the following jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON